# How to close Chrome using Nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
let cp = require("child_process");
console.log("Opening Chrome");
cp.execSync("start chrome");
console.log("Chrome Opened");
```

I have opened the chome using above command but don't know how to close this using similar one.
If anyone of you know let me know!!

Comment: Which OS? Linux, Windows OSx? Crossplatform compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Well here in your program you are relying on some platform command-line tools, so you could try to achieve the same result with a similar platform-specific tool.

For example, there is `kill -9 PID` command that can kill any process, but you need to know the `PID` of your process.

I would advice you to use `spawn` command instead of `execSync` if you just want to spawn some program and have more controll over it.